# Right click with synergy not working

Tags: synergy

I have a windows server and mac client. When I right click on the mac system, I get a context menu (as expected) and then it immediately goes away. The only wayt to get it to work is to click REALLY fast - as in move my finger above my mouse, click, and pull m hand away as fast a I can. If I right click 'casually' - it does not work. It is like it is getting two events... Any ideas?

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Please could you report it? https://github.com/synergy/synergy/issues/new

Answer (score 1):

Does this happen all the time or only sometimes?

If it only happens sometimes, you could try individually pressing all of the option keys on your keyboard a couple of times.

Sometimes Synergy causes some of your keyboard's option keys (usually ALT on Windows) to become stuck and this can cause random issues like the one you're describing.

Comment: Unfortunately - no, this is not the issue. I have definitely seen the one you are describing (quite often) but it is not the case here.